# What are the differences in protein content between chicken broth and chicken stock?

Tags: nutrient-composition, chicken-stock

Does anybody have any data on the nutritional composition of chicken broth (liquid in chicken soup) and chicken stock (liquid from chicken bones)? For example, will stock contain more protein then broth? Have googled the nutritional contents I read conflicting things and I'm not sure whether they are referring to broth or stock.

When during the cooking process is **protein** extracted? If you simmer stock for 2-8 hours, does most of it come out in the first two hours, or does more come out with prolonged simmering?

Comment: This is dangerously close to being a nutrition question. I've refrained from voting to close, because I think as asked it's a factually answerable about effects of cooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very quickly found nutritional information for storebought (Swanson) [chicken broth](http://www.swansonbroth.com/productpopup.aspx?product=nutrition_chickbroth&prd_product_id=11145) and [chicken stock](http://www.swansonbroth.com/productpopup.aspx?product=nutrition_chickenstock&prd_product_id=120867). As you'd expect, neither one contains all that much protein. The stock does contain substantially more: 4g per cup compared to 1g - this should also be expected, since stock has some gelatin in it, and gelatin is mostly protein.

Of course, it's commercially made; I imagine you'd be hard-pressed to find good nutritional data for homemade stock and broth.